# Leaving Iceweasel running remotely

Tags: remote, headless, xorg

I've got a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with Raspbian Jessie Lite. So far I've been happy running it with command line only, but I came up with a use case for a graphical browser, so I installed the X environment and started it:

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg xinit xserver-xorg-video-fbdev lxde lxde-common`

`sudo startx`

Now that works fine and when I connect with a suitable client ([MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html), if that makes any difference) I can run and use Iceweasel browser just fine (`sudo apt-get install iceweasel`, then `iceweasel &`).

However, the issue is now: **how do I leave the Iceweasel running when I quit the SSH session?** If it was a command line application I'd do `nohup iceweasel &`, but it doesn't work in this case... Also, I'd naturally like to be able to reattach the Iceweasel window to my session when I reconnect with SSH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No SSH needed, I ended up [using VNC](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/). Quick instructions:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install realvnc-vnc-server realvnc-vnc-viewer`

`sudo raspi-config` > Interfacing Options > VNC > "Yes"

And now, since it's a headless system, you need to start a virtual desktop:

`vncserver`

It then prints the IP and the display number to the terminal, something like "192.167.5.149:1". You can then use that piece of information to connect to the Raspberry using, say, the [RealVNC Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/).

Answer (score 0):

The program "screen" is what you are looking for.

A simple tutorial:

https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Comment: Thanks, but no, it doesn't seem to do well with graphical apps. The app stays running even when you detach the screen or try to disconnect your SSH session.

Comment: Then you could use xpra.

Comment: Unfortunately, xpra install fails: `sudo apt-get install xpra`: "`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xpra : Depends: xserver-xorg-video-dummy but it is not going to be installed`". Trying to install that gives "`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-dummy : Depends: xorg-video-abi-18`" and that one "`Package xorg-video-abi-18 is a virtual package provided by:
  xserver-xorg-core 2:1.16.4-1+deb8u1 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'xorg-video-abi-18' has no installation candidate`". Finally, `xserver-xorg-core is already the newest version.`???

Comment: Is this the solution ? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50000/cannot-install-xpra-unmet-dependancies

Comment: Getting there... I was able to install xpra now, but trying to start an application inside it results in this error: `MobaXterm X11 proxy: Authorisation not recognised
Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0` I have now read about MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1, but I don't see how that applies, as everything I've read about it concerns getting X11 forwarding to work after you've su'd yourself to some other user, which isn't the case here... :/

Comment: I've posted a follow-up question to Unix & Linux SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384819/unable-to-use-xpra-authorisation-not-recognised